# Control may reach end of non-void function Xcode c++

Tags: xcode, queue

Why am I getting this error??
This wasn't an error until I added this file to Xcode, not sure whats wrong.
In my queue class in the delete function:

```
class queue {

private:
    point* Q[MSIZE];

    int front, rear, size;

public:
    queue() {
        // initialize an empty queue
        front = 0; rear = 0; size = 0;
        for (int j=0; j < MSIZE; ++j)
           Q[j] = 0;
    }

    void insert(point* x) {
        if (size != MSIZE) {
            front++; size++;
            if (front == MSIZE) front = 0;
            Q[front] = x;
        }
    }

    point del() {
        if (size != 0) {
            rear++; if (rear == MSIZE) rear = 0;
            point temp(Q[rear]->getx(), Q[rear]->gety());
            size--;
            return temp;
        };
    } // error "Control may reach end of non-void function" on this line
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function `del` returns a `point`. If size != 0, there's no return statement. You need to return something in the other case, or the function can end without returning a `point`, which generates an error.

One way to fix this since you can't do `return null` is this:

```
bool del(point& pointRef)
{
    if (size != 0)
    {
        rear++;
        if (rear == MSIZE)
        {
            rear = 0;
        }
        pointRef = Q[rear];
        size--;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then outside this function, if you got false, you know nothing happened. If you get true, then you know you have a pointer to the deleted `point`.

Example of calling it:

```
point aPoint;
bool result;

result = del(aPoint);
if(result)
{
    // do stuff with aPoint
}
else
{
    // the queue was empty
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me the error: "No viable conversion from 'long' to 'point'" on the return NULL

Comment: Does `return nil;` work? I'm not at Xcode right now, so I can't check this. Are you sure you're in C++? The code would be in a .mm file.

Comment: Oh, can't return null in C++. Will fix my answer. Just a minute.

Comment: When I call this function I want to access this point and look at its neighbors. The boolean value will not allow me to do this

Comment: Look up what passing a reference does. You give this function a reference to a `point`, then the `bool` tells you if it is valid or not. We are returning the `point` through the argument to the function.